# ¿Es posible desencriptar md5? ¿O crear una función crypt, decrypt?

Tags: php, encriptación

Lo que quiero saber, si es posible desencriptar un `md5` o crear una función para encriptarlo valores aleatorios, y después enviarlos por un `querystring` a otra pagina y desencriptarlo.

Comment: md5 es una función *hash*, **no** de encriptación ni de codificación. Son 3 cosas muy distintas. Deberías aclarar la pregunta. Voto por cerrarla.

Comment: Se habra confundido al redactarla. Qerra decir desencriptar md5 y se ha liado con los terminos. No hay porque cerrarla @Trauma

Comment: Jajajajajaja es cierto confundí los términos xd pero me podrían ayudar :v

Comment: El enlace para [editar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/49564) y aclarar los términos está en el mismo sitio de siempre ;-)

Comment: Gracias :) perdonen mi ignorancia xd

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Puedes probar con este código para encriptar y desencriptar `string`:

```
$key = 'clave';
$string = 'Cadena a encriptar';
```

Encriptar

```
$iv = mcrypt_create_iv(
    mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC),
    MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM
);

$encrypted = base64_encode(
    $iv .
    mcrypt_encrypt(
        MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128,
        hash('sha256', $key, true),
        $string,
        MCRYPT_MODE_CBC,
        $iv
    )
);
```

Desencriptar

```
$data = base64_decode($encrypted);
$iv = substr($data, 0, mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC));

$decrypted = rtrim(
    mcrypt_decrypt(
        MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128,
        hash('sha256', $key, true),
        substr($data, mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC)),
        MCRYPT_MODE_CBC,
        $iv
    ),
    "\0"
);
```

También puedes probar con este código que he sacado del [manual de php](http://php.net/manual/es/function.mcrypt-encrypt.php)

```
<?php
    # --- ENCRYPTION ---

    # la clave debería ser binaria aleatoria, use scrypt, bcrypt o PBKDF2 para
    # convertir un string en una clave
    # la clave se especifica en formato hexadecimal
    $key = pack('H*', "bcb04b7e103a0cd8b54763051cef08bc55abe029fdebae5e1d417e2ffb2a00a3");

    # mostrar el tamaño de la clave, use claves de 16, 24 o 32 bytes para AES-128, 192
    # y 256 respectivamente
    $key_size =  strlen($key);
    echo "Tamaño de la clave: " . $key_size . "\n";

    $plaintext = "Este estring estaba encriptado con AES-256 / CBC / ZeroBytePadding.";

    # crear una aleatoria IV para utilizarla co condificación CBC
    $iv_size = mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC);
    $iv = mcrypt_create_iv($iv_size, MCRYPT_RAND);

    # crea un texto cifrado compatible con AES (tamaño de bloque Rijndael = 128)
    # para hacer el texto confidencial 
    # solamente disponible para entradas codificadas que nunca finalizan con el
    # el valor  00h (debido al relleno con ceros)
    $ciphertext = mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, $key,
                                 $plaintext, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $iv);

    # anteponer la IV para que esté disponible para el descifrado
    $ciphertext = $iv . $ciphertext;

    # codificar el texto cifrado resultante para que pueda ser representado por un string
    $ciphertext_base64 = base64_encode($ciphertext);

    echo  $ciphertext_base64 . "\n";

    # === ADVERTENCIA ===

    # El texto cifrado resultante no tiene añadida integridad o autenticidad
    # y no está protegido contra los ataques de relleno de oracle.

    # --- DESCIFRADO ---

    $ciphertext_dec = base64_decode($ciphertext_base64);

    # recupera la IV, iv_size debería crearse usando mcrypt_get_iv_size()
    $iv_dec = substr($ciphertext_dec, 0, $iv_size);

    # recupera el texto cifrado (todo excepto el $iv_size en el frente)
    $ciphertext_dec = substr($ciphertext_dec, $iv_size);

    # podrían eliminarse los caracteres con valor 00h del final del texto puro
    $plaintext_dec = mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, $key,
                                    $ciphertext_dec, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $iv_dec);

    echo  $plaintext_dec . "\n";
?>
```

Comment: Los probare haber que tal :)

Comment: Funcionan perfectamente, pero lo que yo busco es algo parecido al md5, sha1 o hash, pues con base64 tengo que usar el url encode, y lo quiero generar es una url limpia.

Comment: A lo que me refiero es a que no quiero que el url lleve caracteres como + - / = ?, digamos que quiero que quede así http://url.com/?query=codigogenerado y enviarlo a otra pagina para que sea codificado

Comment: Es lo mismo que `md5`, solo que se usa `sha256` que es mas seguro @AnimationsNow

Comment: Entonces tienes que usar funciones de limpieza de la url no de encriptación @AnimationsNow

Comment: Si lo se, pero es lo que menos quería xD pero bueno gracias :)

Comment: Y otra cosa, si pasas las cosas por `get` debes tener en cuenta que no puedes pasar infinitos caracteres, tienen un limite de caracteres determinado. aqui tienes información al respecto: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2659995/8081356  @AnimationsNow

Comment: Si lo se, gracias :)